# Fetch the first datetime when both value and date matches using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have `2` dataset

```
# df1 - minute based dataset

date_df1              Open_df1
2018-01-01 00:00:00   1.0516 
2018-01-01 00:01:00   1.0516 
2018-01-01 00:02:00   1.0516 
2018-01-01 00:03:00   1.0516 
2018-01-01 00:04:00   1.0516 
....

# df2 - daily based dataset

date_df2      open_df2
2018-01-01    1.0516 
2018-01-02    1.0516 
2018-01-03    1.0516 
2018-01-04    1.0516 
2018-01-05    1.0516 
....
```

**Things to note**

- `df1` is a `minute-based` and `sorted`
- `df2` is `day-based` and `sorted`

**What I want to accomplish?**

- I want to search `df1` `(minute based)`, where each value from `df2`, `date_df2` and `open_df2` match `first` with `df1` and get the corresponding `df1` `(minute based)` and merge it with `df2`

My final `df2` looks like this:

```
# df2 - daily based dataset with first value match date

date_df2      open_df2     date_open_value_first_match_df1
2018-01-01    1.0516       2018-01-01 00:04:00
2018-01-02    1.0516       2018-01-02 01:03:00      
2018-01-03    1.0516       2018-01-03 02:37:00
2018-01-04    1.0516       2018-01-04 00:22:00
2018-01-05    1.0516       2018-01-05 03:12:00
....
```

**What did I do?**

```
df2['date_open_value_first_match_df1'] =
     [df2['date_df2'] == df1['date_df1'] && df2['open_df2'] == df1['Open_df1']].first()
```

What I was trying to do is match the `date` and `open` values and get the `first` date value, however it does not work.

Could someone please help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a common key between the dataframes, merge them, and group by the key and keep the first observation for each group.

```
df1['date_df1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.date_df1)
df2['date_df2'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.date_df2)

df2['key'] = df2['date_df2'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '_' + df2['open_df2'].astype('str')
df1['key'] = df1['date_df1'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '_' + df1['Open_df1'].astype('str')

df2.merge(df1, on='key', how='inner').groupby('key', as_index=False).first().drop(['key', 'Open_df1'], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
    date_df2  open_df2   date_df1
0 2018-01-01    1.0516 2018-01-01
```

Comment: I am looking for minute data too from `df1`

Comment: @floss It still has the timestamp.  For whatever reason `2018-01-01 00:00:00` was shortened to `2018-01-01`.  You can remove the `groupby` to validate.

Comment: How do you change the column name `date_df1` to `date_df1_match`